# Microsoft band tile events not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, microsoft-band

I'm trying to interact with Band just after user tap on a Band's tile. But I cannot figure out, how to do this. With this code, followed by guide on [developers.microsoftband.com](http://developer.microsoftband.com) I have nothing. When I tap on a tile, nothing happens...

Here's a code:

```
using Microsoft.Band;
using Microsoft.Band.Tiles;
using Microsoft.Band.Tiles.Pages;

using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))
{
   //creating tile here
   //...

   if (await bandClient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile))
      {
         bandClient.TileManager.TileOpened += (sender, ev) =>
         {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Opened");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ev.TileEvent.TileId);
         };

         await bandClient.TileManager.StartReadingsAsync();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive Tile events from the Band, you have to maintain a connection to the Band during the time period of interest.  In your sample code, you use a 'using' statement/block to manage the connection to the Band, but the block ends immediately after starting readings from the Band.  This effectively closes the connection to the Band right after you starting listening for Tile events, which is likely why you never receive any.

To receive events from the Band, do not dispose of the IBandClient until the period of time in which you're interested in events has elapsed.

Comment: Yeah, I tried without `using` and it was working. Is there any way to send tile event to the app when this app is not launched on the phone. I need to update data each time user open Band's tile.

Comment: On Windows Phone, no; the application must be running, with an active connection to the Band, in order to receive events from the Band.  This is simply a limitation of the Windows Phone 8.1 platform.  Other platforms, such as Android, are more flexible in how background tasks are triggered.